# How to show overlay image in a certain time span with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm adding an overlay image to a video, which works, but I'd like to show it only in a certain time span:

```
ffmpeg -i video2.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10:enable=between(t\,0\,30)" -codec:a copy out2.mp4
```

This shows the error

```
key 'enable' not found
```

Comment: Next time when asking questions about ffmpeg, please include the full, uncut  command line output as well.

Answer (score 22):

The syntax looks right to me. Use single quotes so you don't have to escape the expression:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,1,2)'" output.mp4
```

If you don't have an `enable` option, make sure you use an ffmpeg version 2.0 or higher. Timeline editing is only supported there (see [Changelog](https://raw.github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/master/Changelog)).

If you want multiple images overlaid, use something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -i watermark2.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,1,2)' [tmp]; [tmp][2:v] overlay=20:20:enable='between(t,2,3)'" output.mp4
```

To define a start point and place the overlay until the end of the video, use `inf` for *infinite*. This example will show it from second 10 until the end of the video:

```
... enable='between(t,10,inf)'
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Can you give me link for ffmpeg version 2.0 or higher.

Comment: You can download any version from the ffmpeg homepage: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html — depends on how you use it on Android though. You might have to compile it from source.

Comment: thank u but getting 1 error unable to find suitable format '[tmp];[tmp][2:v] overlay=20:20:enable='between(t,2,3)'" output.mp4

Comment: Ah, sorry, the newline has to be removed or escaped. Please check my update.

Comment: i m executing update command getting error -
opening an output file:overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,1,2)'.
No such filter ''

Comment: thank u command is working actually command execution minor mistake

Comment: If the command worked, I'd be happy for you to accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Comment: ya i m traying voted up but votedup require 15 reputation  sry for that and Thankx for helping

Comment: I know you cannot vote up yet, but you can always [accept an answer](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) — just click the ✓ next to the answer.

Comment: How to mapping multiple overlay using single image -i watermark.png it's possible or not

Comment: Same idea, you just have to specify the same input image in the filtergraph (e.g. `[1:v]`), or use the same input image twice.

Comment: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -i watermark2.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,1,2)' [tmp]; [tmp][1:v] overlay=20:20:enable='between(t,2,3)'" output.mp4  am i right?

Comment: Something like this, yeah, but the second watermark input is not necessary here.

Comment: yes command is working thanks but more and more adding overlay getting error i am adding overlay >380 up then error

Comment: If you're getting errors with a new command please ask a new question with the command you're using and the full, uncut output. I cannot guess what your error is. By >380 do you mean over 380 images?

Comment: It's possible to not set time ```enable='between(t,2,3)``` but frames??

Comment: @zajca Yes, use `n` instead of `t`.

Comment: The commands works perfectly but the issue is that when used with potrat videos , the merged video is rotated as landscape,can any help me understand why is it doing that .

Comment: @PravinDodia You can try setting the rotation flag on the output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335073/can-i-set-rotation-field-for-a-video-stream-with-ffmpeg/15336581#15336581

Comment: @slhck I did that but , after doing that the images are also rotating which should not, so its a mess, but I think the issue is the version of ffmpeg, which I have updated and will update you all with my results.

Comment: @PravinDodia It's best to ask a new question and give us some sample images, the command you're using, and the full command line output.

Comment: Note that between is inclusive at the end thus it will display an extra frame: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html