# Add Watermark to the bottom right

Tags: ffmpeg, android, query, watermark

I want to add a watermark at the bottom right with query given below,  also shown in this image:

[image]

My command is:

```
String[] command121 = {
"-y",
"-i",inputPath_audio.mp3,
"-loop", "1",
"-i", inputPath_image.jpg,
"-preset", "ultrafast", "-filter_complex", 
[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x175:colors=Yellow:mode=line:draw=full,
format=yuv420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):(main_h-overlay_h) 
[outv]","-map", "[outv]","-map", "0:a", "-c:v",       
"libx264", "-c:a", "aac", "-shortest", output.mp4};
```

And this is my command for the watermark :
                    "[1] scale=70:70 [tmp]; [0][tmp] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10"

But not able to implement in the above query.

Comment: What is the problem with your command? Please explain.

Comment: @slhck i want to add watermark to this command, at this time it just make output without watermark

Comment: There are plenty of questions on adding wartermarks or images over a video (e.g. https://superuser.com/a/714705/48078) – please try looking for answers first.

Comment: yes i have searched about it ,and i have implemented watermark to the other commands, but the problem is to add watermark to this command,its not being implemented with this command.thats why i have asked @slhck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scale, showwaves, vstack, overlay, setsar, and format filters:

```
ffmpeg \
    -loop 1 \
    -i background.jpg \
    -i logo.png \
    -i audio.mp3 \
    -filter_complex " \
        [0]scale=1280:-1[top];
        [2]showwaves=s=1280x174:colors=Yellow:mode=line:draw=full[bottom];
        [top][bottom]vstack=inputs=2:shortest=1[bg];
        [bg][1]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10,format=yuv420p[v]
    " \
    -map "[v]" \
    -map 2:a \
    -c:a copy \
    -preset ultrafast \
    output.mp4
```

Comment: thank you so much for correction but i also want showwaves at the bottom of video and in bottom right corner i want a logo image as watermark ,is it possible ?.

Comment: @Sekhon123 It is unclear to me what you want to achieve. If showwaves is at the bottom, and the overlay is in the bottom right, then what is at the top? You only have two inputs: showwaves and `inputPath_image.jpg`. My example placed showwaves as the whole background with the overlay in the bottom right.

Comment: hello, i have updated the image above to make it clear,actually in this above image --->
Things Done

1. the inputPath_image.jpg is the background image that i have set as shown in above output.
2.showwaves is done with this above query showwaves=s=1280x175:colors=Yellow:mode=line:draw=full ,


Things i want to add in this command...


1. i want watermark at the bottom right in this command.. so what should i add in command (additional) to achieve this logo at the bottom.

Comment: @Sekhon123 Answer updated. I accidentally switched the scale WxH.

Comment: Hello @llogan help me out in one more query..... link : https://superuser.com/questions/1486053/ffmpeg-add-watermark-to-bottom-right-with-spectrum-android