# Add watermark to bottom right with spectrum

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, android, watermark

The output image should look like this below:

[image]

My command is:

```
String[] command1211 = {"-i", inputPath_audio.mp3,
                "-preset", "ultrafast",
                "-filter_complex",
                "[0:a]showspectrum=s=1280x720,format=yuv420p[v]",
                "-map", "[v]", "-map", "0:a", "-c:v", "libx264", "-c:a",
                "copy", filePath.mp4};
```

I want to add watermark to the bottom right with this command.

And this is my command for the watermark:

"[1] scale=70:70 [tmp]; [0][tmp]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h- 
 overlay_h-10"

I achieved it with the following query:

```
String[] command12111 = {
    "-i", inputPath_audio,
    "-i",imagepath.getAbsolutePath(),
    "-preset", "ultrafast",
    "-filter_complex",
    "[0:a]showspectrum=s=1280x720[spec]; 
    [1]scale=70:70[watermark];[spec][watermark]overlay=main_w- 
    overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[output]",
    "-map", "[output]", "-map", "0:a", "-c:v", "libx264",  
    "-c:a",
    "copy", filePath
};
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what the difference is between that and your previous question. The questions you have posted so far are all rather unclear – in fact, there are not even any questions. Please show where exactly you are having problems and what you've tried. I don't see that you've even tried to add a watermark to the command, a solution to which has been given to you in the previous question.

Comment: firstly the difference is that in earlier question its about the logo(watermark) to be placed with the 'showwaves' function and a background image as labled as 'inputPath_image.jpg'  and mp3 file as seen there are three inputs and the fourth is watermark.
And in this question is its totally different ,it only has one input that is mp3 file and watermark with the 'showspectrum' function.
And it seems that you are not getting my point. i am here for asking help in my project and you are not helping at all. these websites are made to share problems and getting solved. not to increase problems

Comment: And you said my questions are unclear.. then why that other guy helped me to solve my previous question. he understands my point thats why i get solved.

Comment: We are expecting users to show research effort. You cannot expect to be able to post a problem here, ask others to solve it for you, and get a solution without showing that you have at least tried to solve it yourself. The fact that you got an answer does not necessarily mean that the question is good, or that we should encourage such questions. In fact, llogan had to ask for some clarification as well. See https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I mean, you show your "command for the watermark" but you haven't even tried to add that to your example command. Why not? What happened when you tried? Your `showspectrum` goes to the `v` label and gets output directly. So obviously the overlay is not there. You have to  add a input, and add a new filter (e.g. `[v][tmp]overlay[out]`) to create an overlay with that input. If you don't know how the input/output labels or filter chains work, then please explain and ask about that instead. But by just "giving you the solution", we're not helping you or anyone else in the long run.

Comment: ok thank you so much for your suggestion.... can you explain these  input/output labels or filter chains work as i don't get from the official ffmpeg website

Comment: Well, you first have to add a new input (`-i audio.mp3 -i image.png`). The audio will have index 0, the image index 1. Each of these inputs can be connected to one or more filters. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide for more info. In your case, the complex filter will be something like `[0:a]showspectrum[spec];[1]scale=70:70[watermark];[spec][watermark]overlay[output]`. You can freely choose the names `spec`, `watermark`, etc. In the end, use `-map "[output]" -map "0:a"` to say that you want thse to be used for the encoded video.

Comment: If you have tried that, please update your question and show whether you ran into any problems. Then I'd consider also reopening it. I understand the filtering is a bit complex, but you have to also understand that we're providing help for free, and for that the community asks you to do a little bit of work yourself.

Comment: @slhck Yes i have tried as you have explained me in the above comment... and no error occured and finally achieved,and thanks for giving me right way....

Comment: And i have updated the question

Comment: I added an answer based on my initial comment. I'm glad you got it work with these hints, and I hope this will help in the future. If you have another ffmpeg question please always try to solve the issue yourself and ask once you get stuck. Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original command is missing the required elements for overlaying a watermark:

1. The watermark image as input
2. The overlay filter to add the watermark

So, you need another `-i` for the watermark input, and an `overlay` filter that connects the spectrum filter output with the image input.

```
ffmpeg \
    -i audio_path \
    -i image_path \
    -filter_complex \
    "[0:a]showspectrum=s=1280x720[spec];
    [1]scale=70:70[watermark];
    [spec][watermark]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[output]
    " \
    -map "[output]" -map 0:a \
    output.mp4
```

Here, it's important to note the labels of the filter inputs (0 and 1 for the respective two inputs) and outputs (`spec`, `watermark`, …). You use these to connect the different filters.

Comment: Can you tell what are these used for  "-c:v", "libx264" , "-c:a" and its not required in command ?

Comment: Please look at the documentation. These select the encoders for video and audio. If you don't select them, ffmpeg will pick some for you.

Comment: You may find the following helpful: https://slhck.info/ffmpeg-encoding-course/#/